# How to send toast message from SFB web SDK to UCMA Bot

Tags: javascript, ucma, ucwa

I am using latest SFB web SDK for connecting audio call with UCMA Bot. I want to send toast message from SFB web SDK to UCMA Bot. I tried with IM call that working fine, but not working in audio call scenario. I search about it, but I haven't found any relevant resources. All blog talks about only how to connect call, not about with toast message. 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your UCMA application that correctly handles your IM scenario you would have registered for incoming IM calls using `localEndpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<InstantMessage>(IMCallDelegate)`.

To handle incoming audio instead of registering `<InstanceMessage>` you need to register for `<AudioVideoCall>` and within that delegate set up event handlers on `call.audioVideoFlowConfigurationRequested` and `call.Flow.StateChanged` events as appropriate.

For example:-
`localEndpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<AudioVideoCall>(AVCallDelegate);`

See the MSDN article of call.AudioVideoFlowConfirgationRequested for more details. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.audiovideo.audiovideocall.audiovideoflowconfigurationrequested_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx